# how can make an automation script for pdf?

Tags: chapters, automation

I have article from 10chapters. How I can make automation for pdf compiling? I need to make several different pdfs without one or two chapters. I can everytime just create another maintex and add /ifalse and /fi near \include {chapter} , but i want to do it without touching code everytime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `excludeonly` to easily set which chapters are not processed (cf. `\includeonly` for the reverse). Just `\include` all chapters, the ones listed in `\excludeonly` will be ignored. MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{excludeonly}
\excludeonly{ch2}

\begin{document}
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}
\end{document}
```

If you like, you can specify the excluded files at compile time on the command line (adapted from [Alex Barnett's (hu)thesis template](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~ahb/thesis/format.html/)):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{excludeonly}

\typein [\files]{Enter file names to exclude, separated by comma, or `none' to process all files:} 
\def\none{none} 
\ifx\files\none
\typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Excluding \files.}
\excludeonly{\files} 
\fi 

\begin{document}
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}
\end{document}
```